# Reducing/Turning Off Particle Effects

Tags: team-fortress-2

After spending much time with a laggy game experience, I've come to the conclusion that certain complex particle effects, particularly those of the Hu-Long Heatmaker minigun for Heavy, and multiple explosions going on at once on-screen, cause my game to lag considerably when in effect.

Is there a way to reduce the complexity or otherwise turn off these particle effects to help reduce my lag?

Comment: This page looks like it has a decent writeup for what the 'advanced' config options are. http://www.nextlevelgamer.com/team-fortress-2/tf2-performance-guide

Comment: Probably the best answer I'll get, unless someone has a console command that can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer, but w/e. Taken straight from the [wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Multiplayer_options):

> **Multiplayer Decal Limit**
>
> The maximum number of decals that can exist at once. Decals are used
>   for visual effects like bullet impacts. Higher numbers will result in
>   more persistent decals, at the expense of performance.

There is a command that represents the Multiplayer Decal Limit, noted by the command `mp_decals x` with *x* denoting the amount of decals you want visible in game.

Since decals are responsible for showing sprays, bullet holes, and other particle effects in game, reducing *x* will in turn lower the amount of particle effects. *X* can be a number from `0 - 200.00`.

If you'd like to have some particle effects (to still show bullet holes, useful for learning recoil patterns and such), an advisable amount is `mp_decals 9`, which is enough for seeing the Scattergun's spread without sacrificing any performance. In Chris' words (creator of Chris' configs)

```
maxframes.cfg

mp_decals 1 // `9' is a good value to still see the spread pattern from a
            // scattergun without any real performance loss.
```